Newly added CSV file is unavailable in QGIS
In QGIS I am trying to add a CSV file to my project that only has a location and coordinates. Whenever I tried to load the file into QGIS the layer was unavailable. How can I fix that?
Here is my workflow: Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer -> choose file name.csv -> file format = custom -> Record and fiel options = decimal separator is comma -> Geometry Definition = Point coordinates (choose X and Y accordingly) -> projections is EPSG:3857 - WG84
I tried moving the CSV file to a shorter path; I tried using dots as delimiters; I tried a TXT file; I changed the call type in the Excel file to "numeric" but nothing worked and I can't see why.
Here are the points I want to use (not the real ones)
ID;lon;Lat
1;3,769070177;6,913269849
2;3,768783623;6,91293787
3;3,780608417;6,911546137
4;3,77924728;6,911425323
5;3,786876021;6,911021632
6;3,794008434;6,911352979
7;3,794192931;6,911396386
8;3,794074327;6,911490433
9;3,793968898;6,911497667
10;3,793863466;6,911512136
11;3,794037427;6,911509242
12;3,794774038;6,913701613
13;3,795780552;6,915063268
14;3,801153772;6,911510689
15;3,801466822;6,911297997
16;3,802396613;6,911206118
17;3,810236213;6,907249815



Works for me. Did you check the semicolon box when selecting the custom separator?

EPSG:3857 is web mercator and uses metres as XY. I think you want EPSG:4326 geographic which uses degrees (lon, lat)

Are those points meant to be in Nigeria?

Read the question carefully: "...points I want to use (not the real ones)".   They are fake coordinates, but it does not matter.

@user30184 "Read the question carefully" I did, and I understood that the points are fake. However, if the fake points are not supposed to be there then the CRS may not be what I think it is.

Ok, good point, nice if the fake data have some meaning.

Import the CSV with Data Source Manager (see the QGIS Documentation | Importing a delimited text file for more details) and make sure:

File Format: set delimiter to Semicolon (uncheck comma)
Record and Fields Options: check the three boxes Decimal separator is comma, the First record has field names as well as Detect field types.
Geometry Definition: check Point coordinates, set X field to lon and Y field to Lat, then for Geometry CRS select EPSG:4326 - WGS 84

Uncheck DMS coordinates (you have checked it on your screenshot: please compare every single setting on my screenshot to make it look exactly the same on your import dialog). As we can see, your coordinates are not in DMS format, so that might be the reason why coordinates are not recognized.
Now, it should look like on the screenshot. Click Add and a point layer should appear in Nigeria, northeast of Lagos.


Thank you everyone, I edited my question and added a screenshot where you can see the settings I used and the unavailable new layer called "nest"


So can you solve the problem with the solution propesed or not? Not clear from your statement if the problem persists. 2) We can't see anything on your screenshot, it's too small.  Please read my answer carefully, use EPSG:4326, not EPSG:3857 and make the exact same settings as on my screenshot. In my case, it worked like this. Be sure to have everything exactly the same.


Hi, no, the problem is still the same. I used the settings you recommended and the layer is there but I can't do anything with it. I made a screenshot how it looks like after I try to add it.

Make a screenshot that shows your settings, like my screenshot. Probably there is still a wrong setting. Large enough to see details.

I just did. Thanks a lot for your persitent help

Everything looks OK, so not sure what goes wrong. In your last screenshot you have a point layer Nest Sites - so probably this is the correct layer? Make sure to select the correct layer and zoom to it. What is strange that in the preview, the datatype is not shown, see my screenshot in comparision. That might be a problem. What QGIS version do you use?

Open the attribute table of the imported CSV: are there any values in the fields for lat/Lon? I suppose the datatype is not correctly recognized and thus these fields are empty. You seem to use an older QGIS version than me, since you don't have the option to manully select the dataypte for each field in the import dialog. Try creating a csvt file instead, see e.g. https://bnhr.xyz/2018/08/07/specifying-csv-data-types-using-a-csvt-file.html or https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/382870/88814 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/38853/88814

No, the attribute table filled and correct. I updated my QGIS and the data type looks okay as well. String for the name and double for lon and lat. I haven't tried the csvt file - as it seems that the data was read correctly

So, then diffficult to say what goes wrong. You should add further information, otherwise it's impossible to help

What kind of information might help? I just created the excel file, put the data in and the converted it to CSV and tried to load it the way I discussed earlier...

Provide the csv file exactly as you use it and provide the resulting layer from QGIS, exported as a Geopackage file. Upload to a cloud service and share the link here

I don't manage to save and export the layer, it tells me "Error: Storing metadata for the specified uri is not supported" , but here is the csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xMfS3TW5lePeM4GIzeWfea29Vw5eefZ/view?usp=sharing

Don't save it to a remote drive or cloud directly: save/export the layer first to your local drive as Geopackage, then upload it. The linked csv file is not accessible, you should make it accessible, otherwise it's not possible to download.

I have no problem importing your shared csv file as point layer. See here for the settings and try to make every singe setting and every checkbox accordingly: https://i.sstatic.net/DdKfCLM4.png Somehow, you seem to make something differently. You have e.g. checked DMS coordinates  - uncheck this (see my screenshot).
